# This tag has the wrong [sizing]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, burninate-request

What is the purpose of the [sizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sizing) tag? It has no usage guidance. I think it’s highly ambiguous and could be used to describe many different types of things. Should it be removed?

Even the tag info says it refers to 2 totally different things - Applicable in screen sizes (html) or load on server (load testing)...and some of the questions aren't related to either of these 2...how is this remotely helpful?

Comment: This is the tag wiki: _“The operation of making appropriate scale according to size which can be dynamic. Applicable in screen sizes (html) or load on server (load testing) Please see other related tags: [tag:resizable] and [tag:resize].”_. Too ambiguous.

Comment: Maybe the questions should be cleaned up and the tag wiki clarified, and then we can make the tag a synonym of e.g. `resize`. I'm not sure that I like burning it, because it's a tag you might naturally reach for while asking a question about sizing user interface components. A quick glance through the questions seems to imply that that's how people are using the tag, even in absence of clear guidelines.

Comment: "Highly ambiguous" isn't a strong reason to burninate a tag. There are a few questions to be answered, when requesting a burnination. Do check them out and [edit] your post with answers to them. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191

Comment: @BhargavRao actually, it's the strongest reason: Tags which fail these tests - commonly referred to as "meta tags" - are effectively meaningless, and **can be actively harmful.**

Comment: @Braiam, "Highly ambiguous" is a strong reason for [meta-tag:tag-disambiguation]. As for burninate requests it is one of the 4 reasons (the 4th reason is ambiguity), all of which are required.

Comment: id say it meets all 4 requirements - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination/324071#324071

Comment: even the tag info says it refers to 2 totally different things - Applicable in screen sizes (html) or load on server (load testing)...and some of the questions aren't related to either of these 2...how is this remotely helpful?

Comment: @Ctznkane525 edit your question instead of posting as a comment

Answer (score 2):

So let's look at its cousins, [size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/size) and [resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/resize)

[size] seems to support removal

> Size in computing can refer to various dimensions: size in bits, in bytes, in pixels, in memory, in disk space, etc.  Please don't use this tag in your posts - it's too generic to usefully categorise(sic) your question.

So that tag is too meta, we've just not cleaned it up (likely due to it having 5k+ questions), but is still describes the questions (even if it's vague). Then we have [resize]

> Issues relating to the resizing of controls, windows, forms or screens.

Still meta but describes the content of the question

So I think rather than burninating this tag, we should synonym it to one of the above tags. So we could

1. Remove [sizing] from anything also tagged [resize] (5 questions)
2. Synonym it to [size] (most closely related)

I can't come up with a good reason to keep a separate tag around for all the various forms of [size].

Comment: "Still meta but describes the content of the question" if it's meta it doesn't describe the content. That's what meta means.